# Get first Unicode character in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to get the first character from a string in a cell.

"Left" function seemed to worked fine, but it returned questions for emoji.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the first one:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^.")
```

Unicode of first value:

```
=UNICODE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^."))
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution were to use

```
=char(code(A1))
```

code - returns the first char unicode value and then I convert it back.